# How to keep count of go routines that are dead?

Tags: go

I have a piece of code where we run multiple go routines multiple to receive values. I am trying to keep count of how many go routines have died due to some exception or error. I don't want to update the count for normal execution.

```
  for {
    go func(){
       err := receiveValues()

    }()
  }
```

Here, receiveValues will call other function and return err if they fail

```
func recieveValues() error{
  if err, val := callSomeFunc(); err != nil{
    return err
  }

  if err2, val2 := callOtherFunc(val); err2 != nil{
    return err2
  }
}
```

I could check when receiveValues() returns error and increment my count, but I also want to increment my count when go routine exits due to some panic or errors that I didn't expect, what will be the fool proof way to keep track to how many go routines have died?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "dead" goroutine. An unrecovered panic crashes the program, but anything else is normal operation.

Comment: You could keep count by, well... keeping a count. At the start of the goroutine you could `defer` incrementing a global int or something. `defer`ed statements still execute in the event of a panic.

Comment: But I only want to keep track fo the go routines if they end due to abnormal conditions such as panic / errors.

Comment: @p-ray: but error are _not_ abnormal, only you can define what that means. An "abnormal" panic should crash the program, so there's not really anything to count there.

Comment: A panic doesn't propagate out of the go routine.

Comment: @p-ray, yes it does, that’s the whole point, panics are meant to terminate the program. https://play.golang.org/p/7sRJXkK7pOV

Comment: This looks like an XY Problem. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Obviously, counting non-existant entities isn't the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use deferred function that will recover from panic.

```
func count() {
    err := recover()
    if err != nil {
        // count error
    } else {
        // count no error
    }
}

func trap() {
    defer count()
    if rand.Intn(2) >= 1 {
        panic("bad luck")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Grzegorz you are a life saver. :D :D :D :D